# kinetic description of an autocatalytic system

Tags: kinetics

I have previously asked this question at physics SE [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/612287/kinetic-description-of-an-autocatalytic-system) and it was suggested to post it here.

I am looking at the system:

$2X + Y \Leftrightarrow 3X $

$A \rightarrow Y$

$X \rightarrow B$

The description in terms of differential equations is this:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^{2}y - x$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = a - x^{2}y$

What is puzzling me is that the fact that 3X are produced is not captured in these equations.

Why is the description not something like

$\frac{dx}{dt} = 3x^{2}y - x - x^{3}$ ?

What fundamental thing am I missing? Help is greatly appreciated.

The source for this is "mathematical models in biology (1987), p 357" by Leah Edelstein-Keshet.

(also, I have a hard time finding relevant tags for this, so please feel free to change)

Comment: In the first reaction only one X is produced net, since two are consumed and three produced. The missing $x^3$ term seems to be due to an assumption that the reverse of the first reaction is negligible. Note that there should be rate constants associated with all reactions that also factor into the rate equations

Comment: ok, that makes sense. My guess is that they set all rate constants to 1 to make the analysis of the system more convenient. thanks! What would the equation look like if the $x^3$ term was *not* ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first assign rate constants to each reaction for completeness:

1. $\ce{2X + Y <=>[k_1][k_{-1}] 3X}$
2. $\ce{A ->[k_2] Y}$
3. $\ce{X->[k_3] B}$

Then let's consider what's happening overall. A is converting to Y, Y is converting to X, and X is converting to B:

$\ce{A ->[k_2] Y <=>[k_1X^2][k_{-1}X^2] X ->[k_3] B}$

Y and X may be in equilibrium, and X catalyzes the X-Y interconversion.

Since X and Y are intermediates, I'm guessing that you are writing the rate equations for them in order to do a steady-state approximation?

Regardless of the purpose, we can see that X is created only in the reaction $\ce{Y -> X}$, which has $\frac{d[\ce{X}]}{dt}=k_1[\ce{X}]^2[\ce{Y}]$. However, it is consumed in two possible reactions, the back reaction $\ce{X -> Y}$ and the forward reaction $\ce{X-> B}$. So the consumption rate is $-\frac{d[\ce{X}]}{dt}=k_{-1}[\ce{X}]^3+k_3[\ce{X}]$. Combining the two equations, we find that

$$\frac{d[\ce{X}]}{dt}=k_1[\ce{X}]^2[\ce{Y}]-k_{-1}[\ce{X}]^3-k_3[\ce{X}].$$

This equation is similar to yours, but complete with rate constants and including the extra term for the reverse reaction. If that reaction is negligible, that term would drop out and give an equation like yours.

For Y, you can use the same process to again get a slightly longer equation than what you have written, because it includes an extra term for formation of Y from X in the back reaction. Clearly the derivation of the equations you provided assumes that only the forward reactions are significant.

Comment: A and B are source and sink, respectively. The book chapter is about the dynamics of the X-Y system and discusses criteria for oscillatory solutions. I believe your assessment of neglectiing the $X^{3}$ term is correct. What puzzled me is that the factor 3 for 3 X produced never appears explicitly, but I assume it is stuffed into the $k_1$ term?

Comment: The 3 doesn’t appear because only one X is produced in that reaction. You could describe it as 3 produced and put in that 3 factor, but then you would have an additional term for the 2 “consumed” in the same reaction and they would add up to what I have written